# how to add a counter updating when you scroll down a page

Tags: javascript, scroll, autoscroll, onscroll

How can I add a counter updating when you scroll down a page? I like the effect that chartbeat has. What jQuery should I use to be able to achieve that?

Comment: You need to describe what it is that you want to implement, ideally *also* link to the site. Your question should stand alone without needing, and relying on, external resources for explanation and clarity.

Comment: We'd appreciate that. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [scrollTop() function](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). You bind event handler to 'scroll' event on document and put the value in place you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).bind('scroll', function() {

    console.log($(this).scrollTop());
  });
});
```

Comment: So, jQuery answers are acceptable? For due reference it might be best to specify that in your question, or the tags to your question.