# JQuery:Calculate Percentage Scroll Error

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new in JQuery. Help me I got Error `Microsoft JScript runtime Error:'$'is Undefined`

[See more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777667/jquery-percentage-increases-as-user-scrolls)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var startValue = 70; // scrollTop value when to start incrementing
        var stopValue = 300; // scrollTop value when to stop incrementing
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > startValue && scrollTop <= stopValue)
            $("#pct").text((((scrollTop - startValue) / (stopValue - startValue)) * 100).toFixed(0));
        else if (scrollTop <= startValue)
            $("#pct").text(0);
        else if (scrollTop >= stopValue)
            $("#pct").text(100);
    });
</script>
 <style type="text/css">
     body {
        height:2000px;
      }

     #pct {
         height:150px;
         width:150px;
         background-color:#369;
         font:bold 60px verdana;
         padding:20px;
         position:absolute;
         top:400px;
         left:200px;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
 <body>
 <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> 
 <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
 <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
 hi
 <div id="pct">0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbSNA/)
It works in jsFiddle but not in IE is somthing missing help me?
Thanks

Comment: This means you're not loading jQuery properly.

Comment: Yes may be but how to load it properly?

Answer (score 2):

You're most likely missing the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i download it and then use it locally but still getting same error

Comment: @YKJ Do you have the script included via the above line, in the `<head>` of your document, before your script above?  Simply having it in the folder isn't enough.

Comment: I wish I could upload image so that what Explain it nicely. Sorry this is giving popup showing above error

Comment: Please edit your question and add the head of the document, showing how you load jquery.

Comment: I added  my page have a look on it.

Comment: It looks correct, assuming the path is right. Like I said above, are there any error messages in the Javascript console, complaining that it can't load jquery.min.js?

Comment: Can you give us the URL to the page

Comment: Sorry I unable to create URL because i am doing it locally

Comment: Sorry, it's impossible for us to tell what's wrong then. Everything you need to know should be in the Javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

use latest jquery file

http://jsfiddle.net/nbSNA/12/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 70 && scrollTop <= 300)
        $("#pct").text((((scrollTop-70)/(300-70))*100).toFixed(0));
    else if (scrollTop <= 70)
        $("#pct").text(0);
    else if (scrollTop >= 300)
        $("#pct").text(100);
});
```

Comment: That won't work. The argument passed to an event handler is the event, not the jQuery function.

Comment: I use this but i think something is missing. is there any thing needed to initialize?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the jquery library before you make calls to it, even if the calls are in other scripts, references to them should appears after the jquery include.